# achieve effect similar to jibjab cards

Tags: php, apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have a good understanding of everything up until the actual embedding in the video.

Anyone know the best way of doing this?

http://sendables.jibjab.com/ecards

Answer (score 0):

To play a video in flex, use the [VideoDisplay](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/VideoDisplay.html) control. If you are using Flash CS3, there is [FLVPlayback](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/video/FLVPlayback.html) control.